# Override the return of a SerializedName

Tags: java, json, gson

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass1 {

   @SerializedName("elements")
   public List<MyInnerClass1> elements;

   public static class MyInnerClass1 {
      //
      // Stuff
      //
   }
}
```

But now I want to extend this class and override the *elements*

```
public class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {

   @SerializedName("elements")
   public List<MyInnerClass2> elements;

   public static class MyInnerClass2 extends MyInnerClass1 {
      //
      // New Stuff
      //
   }
}
```

When I try to run this, it gives me an error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class MyClass2 declares multiple JSON fields named elements
```

I tried to add an `@Override`, but it says it is not an applicable field.

Is there a way to override or is there any good solution?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this issue?